# Total number of carbon atoms in buckminsterfullerene

Tags: molecular-structure, carbon-allotropes

From what I read, buckminsterfullerene is composed of 60 carbon atoms, $\ce{C_{60}}$ and it is made up of 20 hexagons and 12 pentagons. So, I decided to do a back of the hand calculation with the knowledge that each of these were tri-atomic junctions. Since one hexagonal tri-atomic site would comprise a $\ce{C-C}$ bond angle of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, thus just $\frac{1}{3}$rd of an atom and hence two atoms in a hexagon. Since there are 20 hexagons, this gives me 40 atoms. Now the $\ce{C-C}$ bond angle at the pentagon site is $\frac{3\pi}{5}$ which makes it $\frac{3}{10}$ atoms per site and hence $\frac{3}{2}$ atoms per pentagon. With 12 pentagons, it results in 18 atoms. So the total number of atoms according to this calculation amounts to 40+18=58. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Now that's a nice trick indeed. Think of it this way: forget the angles, just count the atoms, as if there were six in each hexagon and five in each pentagon. That would make 180. But wait, we've just counted each atom more than once. Like you said, each atom is on the junction of three polygons, hence it must have been counted three times, so ${180\over3}=60$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but, the atoms for the corners of the pentagons cannot be counted as $\frac{1}{3}$rd since those atoms are just $\frac{3}{10}$ths. If we do that then we get $20*6*\frac{1}{3} + 12*5*\frac{3}{10}$ equalling 58. What you're telling me to do is $20*6*\frac{1}{3} + 12*5*\frac{1}{3}$ equalling 60, but I can't assume a $\frac{1}{3}$rd for the atoms within the pentagon or maybe I think I can't and I should where in the problem becomes, why should I have to consider a fraction of $\frac{1}{3}$ for the atoms in the pentagons as well and not $\frac{3}{10}$ ?

Comment: Because if you count them as $3\over10$, then each atom (which, BTW, is a junction of two hexagons and a pentagon) is counted as ${1\over3}+{1\over3}+{3\over10}={29\over30}$, rather than a full solid $\mathbf1$.

Comment: Yes, but because the fullerenes are spherical balls and not graphene sheets, hence there needs to be some pyramidization, which is why the sums of the fractions need not necessarily be equal to one. Think of it as the apex angles of every triangle of each of the faces of the pyramid of Giza, the sum of the apex angles need not add up to $2\pi$ but if I flatten the pyramid out into a mesh of 4 2D triangles, then the apex angles would need to add up to $2\pi$, similarly the fractions of the out of plane pyramidized figure need not add up to 1.

Comment: Surely the angles need not add up to $2\pi$. The fractions, however, **do** need to add up to 1. This is a certain place in the molecule; it is occupied by one atom. You can't split atoms.

Comment: Let's try counting the vertices of a cube this way. Each face has 4 corners with an angle of $\frac\pi2$, which is $\frac14$ of a full angle, so 1 vertex per face. There are 6 faces so a total of 6 vertices, but obviously a cube has 8 vertices... clearly this method doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @IvanNeretin   Yes the problem is that I was treating these atoms as if they were planar and was hence landing up with a situation where I was defining the fraction as $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$ and at every pyramidized junction $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}+\frac{\beta}{2\pi}+\frac{\gamma}{2\pi} < 1$ and hence I would never have a full atom counted. The sum of errors I guess added up to 2 atoms. Still, thank you very much for being patient with me and for clearing my doubt about the subject.

Comment: @f'' Yes, I realized a second folly in my approach. There will be parts of an atom not within any closed structure and I will miss out on them too. The approach only works if all my atoms are enclosed in a circuital structure and if all the circuital structures are planar. Thank you very much for your answer. It was a great help.

Comment: Fun fact, [Descartes' theorem of angular defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect#Descartes.27_theorem) states that if you do this on any polyhedron without holes, you'll always be off by 2.